# typescript error when no object on find() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

when there is no realestse products on my app, there is no realestate object and then when i trt

when `products.find((x:any) => x.code === 'realestate')` is not found anything, I get an typescript error exctly here, how I can fix that?

`let REItemsGeos: string[] = response.products.find((x:any) => x.code === 'realestate').items.map((({ geo }) => geo))`

This is the variable that it jump the error...

Comment: Could you please mention what is that typescript error you are getting?

Comment: TypeError: Internal server error
    at getUserSummary - this the function that the variable inside it

Comment: Check this for more information http://net-informations.com/q/mis/500.html

Comment: that function run on the backend, but its happen bacause of that line of code for sure...

Comment: i get 500  Internal server error

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether your product exists before mapping:

```
let product = response.products.find((x:any) => x.code === 'realestate');
if (product )
   let REItemsGeos: string[] = product.items.map((({ geo }) => geo))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use optional chaining (`?.`) operator. Will proceed to items.map only when find has not null/undefined value.

```
let REItemsGeos: string[] = response.products
  ?.find((x: any) => x.code === "realestate")
  ?.items?.map(({ geo }) => geo);
```